# How to add optional parameters in a django view keeping the same url

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have the following URL:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/project_page/1/`

and my `urls.py`:

```
path(
    'project_page/<int:pid>/', 
    views.project_page,
    kwargs={'approvalid': None},
    name='project_page'
),
```

Generally speaking, the users will always access via `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/project_page/1/` , but in some cases I want to pass an optional parameter so that the page renders optional content.

For example, if the user access: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/project_page/1/somevalue`

I would like to see the content of `somevalue` in my view, like:

```
def project_page(request, pid, somevalue):
    if somevalue:
        #do something here with the optional parameter
    else:
        #run the view normally
    return render(request, 'mypage.html', context)
```

Once we get the optional parameter, I want the url structure to be the original:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/project_page/1/somevalue` -> get the value of the optional parameter and get back to the original url -> `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/project_page/1/`

What I've tried:

I thought `kwargs` would do the trick, but I did something wrong.

I found this from the official docs ([Passing extra options to view functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#views-extra-options)) but it seems that I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT:

```
def project_page(request, pid, somevalue):
    context = {}
    context['pid'] = 'pid'
    if approvalid:
        context['nbar'] = 'example1'
        #some logic here
    else:
        context['nbar'] = 'example2'
        #some logic here
    return render(request, 'mypage.html', context)
```

Comment: return redirect can be used?

Comment: @Akram I think just `render`

Comment: @Checknov If you use render the url wont change it will show the page with somevalue url.Instead just get somevalue from the url and redirect to the url which does not contain somevalue

Comment: Is it possible to change the url in the request? To remove the `/somevalue/`?

Comment: Is using query parameters not an option? Like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/project_page/1?my_param=somevalue`

Comment: @BrianDestura It's an option, as long as I can get rid of the `?my_param=somevalue` after loading the page, I assume `redirect` is not a good option since I need to send a context.

Comment: How about building the context on when `some_value` is not present? Can you share an example

Comment: Thanks for your comment @BrianDestura, the `context` is always present wether `somevalue` is present or not. I edited my question with a dummy example.

Comment: Right ok. I dont think redirect can do something about this. Perhaps [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) can be used. So when the query param is present, save it to the session and redirect. Then read from the session and build the context?

Comment: @BrianDestura sounds reasonable, could you provide an example?

Comment: Ok posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to use query parameters, you could use Django's [**`sessions`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) to save `somevalue`, redirect to the same url but without the query parameters, then build the context based on that.

Something like this (not tested):

```py
def project_page(request, pid):
    context = {}
    some_value = request.GET.get('somevalue')

    if some_value:
        # if somevalue is present in the query parameters, 
        # save it to the session and redirect
        request.session["approval_id"] = some_value
        return redirect('project_page')

    if request.session.get("approval_id"):
        context['nbar'] = "example1"
    else:
        context['nbar'] = "example2"

    return render(request, "mypage.html", context)
```

Comment: The part you posted is clear, what is not clear to me is the `urls.py` part and how to call the view `project_page(request, pid)` with an optional parameter. Creating another view that saves data in the session and redirects to `project_page(request, pid)` perhaps?

Comment: Query params (or GET parameters) are not part of the url path and are accessible through the request (via `request.GET`), so no need to change your `urls.py`. As long as you use the format `project_page/1?somevalue =somevalue`